# R-CNN in R for analyzing aerial photos

Tags: r, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have 8,000 drone photos on which we want to detect almost circular holes in the ground (no UFOs..). I have been reading and practicing quite a lot with using CNNs in R, using both Keras and Tensorflow. However, I think what I need is a R-CNN instead of a conventional CNN, to be able to scan through the photos looking for the object.

But is there any way to work with R-CNN or even Mask R-CNN in R? I have no experience with Python.

Comment: here is a useful link : https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/index.html#section-recurrent-layers

Answer (score 2):

As you are familiar with using `Keras` and `Tensorflow` in R, you should be able to implement the architecture as per your needs. You will be able to find the rough architecture of most models with a simple Google search and then tweak it to fit your use case.

For example - Faster RCNN architecture.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! However, I have difficulties combining what I have learned so far with Keras and Tensorflow (reproducing examples like classifying images) with a new approach of the R-CNN concept. Are there any tutorials on this using R?